# Creating an FTP Hosting Server Website?

Tags: iis, ftp, hosting

I recently bought a new web server 2008 for our company and require a FTP Hosting site that allows customers to upload files and host websites from our server, The site must have the shopping basket / Monthly rates built in.
If I purchased the correct template that is designed for hosting, How do I get it to work with the web server independently ? (e.g. Creating sub domains, user directories, so on)
The services should be exactly like as this link : https://www.godaddy.com

I have all the equipment & software
How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spend a lot of time and money developing software that provides that functionality in a manner that a potential customer would go somewhere else.

You can install software like CPanel and others that make managing server functionality a lot easier. You can try third party shopping basket software but you may find that it is too generic for your specific needs, and again there will be integration software development to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to cause offense, but it sounds like you're **way** in over your head here.

From the sound of it, hosting websites isn't your company's primary business. If you're the guy in charge of setting up a hosting service, and you're on here asking "how do I set up a GoDaddy clone?", the end result is going to be *very upset customers*.

Stick to your core competencies, or at least hire a professional who has set this sort of thing up before.